# Jquery Timer Slide function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

Right now I have a div that slides right to left and then vice versa back to its original place. But overall its not really how I want it to work. My main goal: is for the user to hover over the main div which will then pull out the sliding div. The part that gets tricky is the following: If the user forgets to slide the dive back, I want to give it time frame that will cause it to close automatically after a certain time has passed. Here is my working code so far: [jsfiddle.net/eMsQr/14/](http://jsfiddle.net/eMsQr/14/).

My JavaScript function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#arrow").hover(
    function(){
      $("#inner").stop().animate({marginRight: "0px", opacity: "1px", height: "100px"}, 500 );
    },
    function(){}
  );
});


$("#arrow").click(function(e){
    $("#inner").stop().animate({marginRight: "-100px", opacity: "1px", height: "100px"}, 500 );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eMsQr/52/)** that sets a 3 second delay via the setTimeout function.:

jQuery

```
var cto;
$("#arrow").hover(
function() {
    clearTimeout(cto);
    $("#inner").stop().animate({
        marginRight: "0px",
        opacity: "1px",
        height: "100px"
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    cto = setTimeout(function(){$('#arrow').trigger('click')}, 3000);
});


$("#arrow").click(function(e) {
    $("#inner").stop().animate({
        marginRight: "-100px",
        opacity: "1px",
        height: "100px"
    }, 500);
});​
```

Note that if the user moves his mouse away and then returns it to the div, the box remains open again until they leave at which point the 3 second countdown timer begins.

Comment: Works good, but that sliding div called "inner" is a form where the user needs to input information. Is there a possible way where it start the time once the user leaves the sliding div called "inner.

Comment: Here's a new jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eMsQr/59/. The form div will stay open as long as the mouse is over it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/vansimke/cJ5pf/

I hooked into the mouseleave event and added a setTimeout. You might need to catch the timeout if you need to cancel it later (i.e. they reenter the arrow)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you utilize the second `function()` in jQuery's `hover` method.

At the moment you're only animating your slide-out div when the user hovers over the main div.  You want it to also animate on hover *out*.

Here's the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eMsQr/48/).

Answer (score 0):

Inside the hover function you can add an additional line to trigger the click event using the below line:

```
setTimeout(function() { $("#arrow").trigger('click'); }, 5000);
```

the `5000` is the number of milliseconds to wait before triggering the click.

Answer (score 0):

see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eMsQr/51/

it uses the `mouseleave` jquery and also `delay`.  Change the value in the delay to get the time you want.

```
$("#arrow").mouseleave(function(){   
    $("#inner").stop().delay(500).animate({marginRight: "-100px", opacity: "1px", height: "100px"}, 500 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setTimeout()` to set the delay to closing the div. You also need to use `clearTimeout()` in the opening function to stop it auto closing if someone mousesout, then back over again:

```
var timeout;
$("#arrow").hover(
    function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout); // clear the timer which will close the div, as we now want it open
        $("#inner").stop().animate({
            marginRight: "0px",
            opacity: "1px",
            height: "100px"
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#inner").stop().animate({
                marginRight: "-100px",
                opacity: "1px",
                height: "100px"
            }, 500);                
        }, 1000); // close the open div 1 second after mouseout.
    }
);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eMsQr/56/)

Comment: Works good, but that sliding div called "inner" is a form where the user needs to input information. Is there a possible way where it start the time once the user leaves the sliding div called "inner.